# unable to generate pinvoke for extern c int _clrcall ... calling convention missing in metadata

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a challenge running my project in Visual C++, by getting the above error. I linked some 2 third party .lib files (`libglorycolx2010.lib & libglyde.lib`) into the project which i successfully did but still getting the error. What might be the problem or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to mix both C++/CLI and C++ code. These are two separate languages. What is confusing to newcomers to Visual C++ is that it is possible to put code for both in the same source file.

However, winpcap is clearly meant to be for straight C++ code. If it's alright with you, simplify your program so that it is 100% unmanaged. That is, instead of using WinForms, stick with either MFC, plain Windows, or a console program. Trying to get C++/CLI to mesh with unmanaged code is a skill that requires a strong knowledge about C++/CLI.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22fd5e36-084f-4a3d-896b-4aed820066e2/visual-c-2010-express-and-winpcap-compiling-issues?forum=Vsexpressvc

Comment: Also Remember to add the library path to Additional Library Directories which is under the “Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General” tab